# Query on unnamed range of a sheet with specific characters (e.g. space, #) in the sheetname

Tags: sql, excel, range

Using ADO and SQL, I know how to query on a spreadsheet, e.g.,

```
Select * from [Sheet1$A1:B10]
```

but when the sheetname is with a space or other specific characters, like #, the reference won't work in the following way:

```
Select * from ['Sheet 1$'A1:B10]
Select * from ['Sheet 1$A1:B10']
```

However, if I choose the whole worksheet, it has no problem.

```
Select * from ['Sheet 1$']
```

With space character, the solution is easy, as shown by Araon D:

```
Select * from [Sheet 1$A1:B10]
```

But with # character, it does NOT work in this way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try `Select * from ['Sheet 1!$A1:B10']`. Cheers

Comment: Error, it's not a valid name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731047/unable-to-query-named-range-on-sheet-with-spaces-in-name-in-excel

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Space in the sheetname is solved, but seems like sheetname with some specific characters, like #, still not working, e.g. sheetname is Sheet#1.