# SQL Server OPENROWSET Select From Excel Table

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am attempting to parse an Excel(xlsx) file into SQL Server. There are many tables within one sheet and I am unsure how to handle this.

I know that I can pull the entire worksheet with this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0; Database=\\afcn2011\root\DATA\VisualCron\SharePoint\Templates\Kitchen+Bar Inventory.xlsx; HDR=NO; IMEX=1',
        'SELECT * FROM [Inventory$]'
    )
```

But I am hoping there is a way to just select from a specific table within the worksheet?

For example, I have a table for each type of liquor; Vodka, Gin, Bourbon, etc. and they are all named "VodkaTable", "GinTable", "BourbonTable", etc.

Is there a way to just select from that specific table? Keep in mind that the range can change over time, so I cannot just say $A10:$B20 or anything like that.
But something like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0; Database=\\afcn2011\root\DATA\VisualCron\SharePoint\Templates\Kitchen+Bar Inventory.xlsx; HDR=NO; IMEX=1',
        'SELECT * FROM [Inventory$VodkaTable]'
    )
```

I have tried this as well now:
I defined a name that refers to the Vodka Table called "VodkaData":
[image]

I then used this query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0; Database=\\afcn2011\root\DATA\VisualCron\SharePoint\Templates\Kitchen+Bar Inventory.xlsx; HDR=NO; IMEX=1',
        'SELECT * FROM [VodkaData]'
    )
```

But I get this error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'VodkaData'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'VodkaData' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a [named range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-in-excel-adee78ff-bcf0-4283-8c29-83304ca0c29d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in the sheet.

Then you can access it with `OPENROWSET` like so:
`'SELECT * FROM [MyNamedRange]'`

Incidentally, I would **really** avoid doing this from T-SQL unless you really need to. SSIS and other tools are much better suited.

Comment: I added some more detail in my question, as I just tried this, but I get an error.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Worksheet:MyNamedRange]`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731047/unable-to-query-named-range-on-sheet-with-spaces-in-name-in-excel

Comment: Sorry `SELECT * FROM [Worksheet$MyNamedRange]`

Comment: Yeah, that is actually what I thought you meant, so I had tried that as well, but the same issue. I am currently attempting to log in locally to the server that holds the file to see if it is some sort of permissions thing.

Comment: Even locally it still does not work. Might have to go with the SSIS solution. Just not as familiar with it.

Comment: Even when I try and import just using the basic SQL Import/Export Task, the views/tables do not show up. It only shows the one worksheet and the Print Area defined area.